# c# Activate panel on form1 from form2

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

So I'm working on a ordering system, when order gets placed from form2, to show a panel with message on form1.. but It doesnt seem to work, please help

```
                int chkComm1 = comm1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if(chkComm1 == 1)
            {
                //so basically if query call is successful (which it is) it should open a panel with message on my main program or form1, but It doesnt work? anyone help?
                Main_Program mp = new Main_Program();
                mp.orderALERT.Enabled = true;
                mp.orderALERT.Visible = true;
                mp.Refresh();

            }
```

After this code it should show panel but nothing happens, if someone can help me please do! Thanks !

Comment: Is `Main_Program` a form?  You're not showing that form.  Unless `Refresh()` is supposed to do that?

Comment: yeah it's a windows form aka my main program, it looks like this: https://i.gyazo.com/f8e154253c1ad15412686e77f2ec053a.png and it shoould show that message that I use in green after I click "PAY" from second form, to notify that there is a new order available. Message is by default hidden untill there is active order. Refresh should refresh main program after it would appear, but nothing happens..

Comment: Ok, but you never call `.Show()` on your form instance.  You can't display something on a form if you never show that form in the first place.  I suspect you *already have* an instance of that form somewhere?  In which case you shouldn't be making a new one.  (As I write this an ever-improving answer is being written below, you should definitely go there.)

Comment: Its already open in background. Its like the starting form when u start the program. And Second form is opened without closing this main program form. But my main program form doesnt update when I execute that program i posted. Either its wrong code or im doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** Your code is not working, because you create new instance of form1 which is not related to main form which you already have in your application:

```
Main_Program mp = new Main_Program(); // here
```

**Solution:** You should use form1 which is already opened. That is easy to do with events. Create an event on form2:

```
public event EventHandler OrderPlaced;
```

And raise it when order is placed:

```
int chkComm1 = comm1.ExecuteNonQuery();

if(chkComm1 == 1)
{
    OrderPlaced?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

On form1 subscribe to event of form2:

```
form2.OrderPlaced += Form2_OrderPlaced;
```

And in event handler activate panel:

```
private void Form2_OrderPlaced(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    orderALERT.Enabled = true;
    orderALERT.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: I got this msg for some reason :O? https://gyazo.com/7bb42d029b401f60e1efe964706229d6

Comment: @Rin make sure `PAY` is an *instance* of form2

Comment: @Rin it looks for me as class name

Comment: When I try to access PAY.OrderPlaced it doesnt even show as I dont have access? https://gyazo.com/c5178dcc11ad80733a55a7a21a5dc7fb

Comment: @Rin have you defined event in `form2` as stated above? `public event EventHandler OrderPlaced;`

Comment: Yep, did all as you said:) still same error :s https://i.gyazo.com/0030db44f83cbd1693f90b863357d037.png

Comment: @Rin check your code carefully - you have used `static` keyword somewhere. Here is error description https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120

Comment: I'm using few "public static string id;" to store my ID for some stuff so I can use it in all forms:) but I dont see how that causes any trouble :O

Comment: @Rin it's hard to tell without seeing your code to see where you are calling non-static member from static method. Check error description from MSDN and compare it with your code. Sorry, I'm AFK now

Comment: I'm only using few , heres img to where https://gyazo.com/5e09c0561e015678d93a8ba0b242f334 I also have 2 more on other form at the same spot. but I dont think thats causing the error.

Comment: HEY I FIXED IT! :))) IT was supposed to be with STATIC included, only then I CAN call event from different form -->> "public **static** event EventHandler OrderPlaced;" and not "public event EventHandler OrderPlaced;" as you said ;) Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Pass in your instance of Main_Program to the `Show()` method of Form2 like this:

```
public partial class Main_Program : Form
{
    public Main_Program()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show(this); // pass in THIS instance of Main_Program as the "Owner"
    }

}
```

Now, over in Form2, you can cast the `Owner` back to Main_Program and manipulate.  To access your "orderALERT" Panel, however, you must change its `Modifiers` property to public:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Owner != null && this.Owner is Main_Program)
        {
            Main_Program mp = (Main_Program)this.Owner;
            mp.orderALERT.Enabled = true;
            mp.orderALERT.Visible = true;
            mp.orderALERT.Refresh();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It works perfectly in my mock-up example, so you're doing something wrong.  Make sure you don't have any `new` keywords making instances of Main_Program.  Also make sure you don't have any Try/Catch blocks hiding exceptions by doing nothing with them.

Comment: Hmm, weird, is there any other approach? EDIT: I tried again, it wont work for me::(

Comment: Then there is something about your setup that either isn't quite right, or that you haven't explained in great enough detail.

Comment: I managed to do it with other guys solution that posted above you, but I still will try to figure out why this one wont work for me for educational purposes:) Thanks for helping bro! :)))